# What is the format of the crostini backup .tini file?

Tags: chromium-os, crostini

Crostini backup creates a xxx.tini file.  What is the format of this file?  Is there a way to view the file list of this file, ideally from within the Chromebook?

Answer (score 3):

The format does not appear to be documented at the Crostini developer site so the following is based on checking an actual backup experimentally! (If someone finds a link, please add it or comment.)

This is a `tar` archive which is compressed with `gzip` with structure as follows:

- The file system (usually `/dev/vdb` in `btrfs` format) mounted as `/` in the container is stored under the top-level directory `rootfs` in this archive. Note that this *includes* the `rootfs/home` sub-directory and its contents so be careful what you do with copies of the `.tini` file.
- In addition, there is a top-level `metadata.yaml` file of which a version is reproduced below.
- In addition, there is a top-level directory `templates` which contains the files `hosts.tpl` and `hostname.tpl` which are referred to in the `metadata.yaml` file. Presumably, this allows for additional templates to be added at a later stage via the metadata file.

`metadata.yaml` contents:

```
architecture: amd64
creation_date: 1573104613
expiry_date: 1575696613
properties:
  architecture: amd64
  description: Debian buster amd64 (20191107_05:24)
  name: debian-buster-amd64-default-20191107_05:24
  os: debian
  release: buster
  serial: "20191107_05:24"
  tremplinSetupFinished: "true"
  variant: default
templates:
  /etc/hostname:
    when:
    - create
    - copy
    create_only: false
    template: hostname.tpl
    properties: {}
  /etc/hosts:
    when:
    - create
    - copy
    create_only: false
    template: hosts.tpl
    properties: {}
```